# Can I receive an NDEF_DISCOVERED Intent after writing an empty NDEF Message?

Tags: android, nfc, iso, ndef

I am developing an application in Android regarding NFC tags. When I write an empty NdefMessage to a NFC tag using IsoDep and APDUs, would I then when I receive a new intent be able to receive an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent?

At the moment I would just get an ACTION_TECH intent and I wonder whether the written APDU is wrong or if NDEF_DISCOVERED is just not possible when an empty NDEFMESSAGE was written.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no such thing as an empty `NdefMessage` and `NdefMessage` really just an array of correctly formatted `NdefRecords`

If you read the NDef Spec https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-NDEF_1.0.pdf

A Message is just a series of Ndef Records with the first one having the "Message Begin" record flag set and the last one having the "Message End" record flag set.

If you look the Android source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/nfc/NdefMessage.java#63

if you have zero records in the array then the `NdefMessage` is null.

So you are writing zero bytes to the Tag, there is nothing for the Android NFC system App to identify it as not a blank Tag.